# Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am uploaded Multi File Using Web api with jquery. In my one localhost application i upload multiple file using look like this:

[image: Multiple file upload]

Now, When i click the submit button all files data, images are save in using web api through second localhost application. my form code describe here.

[image: Code Description]

When i press submit button gives error.. That display below:
[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable cross origin in your WebAPI like below

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://yourdomain", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

Comment: How to enable cross origin in web api??

Comment: First install Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors package from nugget. Alternatively refer [http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Comment: Hi that work for me but when i post 2 files than call two times but i haven't get files details..

Comment: hi any one help how to save that multiple files in cross domain. it means my two file posted the other localhost than how can i save that file in server??